# How do I convince mod_proxy_ajp to pass environment variables to its backend?

Tags: apache, wsgi, ajp

I'm trying to use Apache's `mod_proxy` with the `AJP` backend and an ajp-wsgi app server but it doesn't seem to be sending `SetEnv` variables to the application server.

Configuration snippet:

```
<Location /script>
    ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/script
    SetEnv FOO "barbobot"
</Location>
```

How do I pass environment variables from the Apache configuration to my app server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to prefix the environment varibles with `AJP_`, as in

```
<Location /script>
    ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/script
    SetEnv AJP_FOO "barbobot"
</Location>
```

See http://marc.info/?l=apache-httpd-dev&m=122059722411298&w=2